# Why my jekyll site on github not work with mathjax?

Tags: github, jekyll, mathjax

I start to build a jekyll site on github following this [BLOG](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/).

OK it works.[image: changkaizhao.github.io]

I would like to add some math stuffs in my blog, I add a "mathjax.html" in "include folder"

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
      TeX: {
                equationNumbers: {
                            autoNumber: "AMS"
                                  }
           },
      tex2jax: {
                inlineMath: [ ['$','$'],
                            ['\(', '\)'] ],
                displayMath: [
                            ['$$','$$'] ],
                processEscapes:true,
               }
                 });
```

and then include this file in Layouts files(default.html page.html  post.html)

```
    <div class="wrapper-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <footer class="footer">
          {% include svg-icons.html %}
        </footer>
      </div>
   </div>
      {% include analytics.html %}
 </body>
  </html>
 {% include mathjax.html %}
```

default.html

```
---
layout: default
---
{% include mathjax.html %}

<article class="page">

<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

<div class="entry">
  {{ content }}
</div>
</article>
```

page.html

```
---
layout: default
---
<article class="post">
 <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

 <div class="entry">
  {{ content }}
 </div>

 <div class="date">
   Written on {{ page.date | date: "%B %e, %Y" }}
 </div>
  {% include disqus.html %}
 </article>
 {% include mathjax.html %}
```

post.html

and add this line in post file

```
$$ sin(x^2) $$
```

As a result ,the page show nothing ...
what 's wrong with it?

Comment: what's strange is the mathjax works well while open the post page locally : localhost:4000

Comment: Try: `$$sin(x^2)$$`.
Also check you are using Kramdown locally.
Github pages supports only Kramdown. but your local jerkyll probably supports several others, which you might be using by mistake. (It should default to kramdown, though)

Comment: in __config.yml_  I set  `markdown: kramdown`   I can't figure out what wrong with my operation...

Comment: It is confounding. Try `\(x^2\)`?

Comment: not work it shows `(x^2)` directly

Comment: @Roby your code snippets includes a MathJax configuration but not a script tag that actually loads it. Kramdown pre-processes TeX into MathJax's custom script tags; these will be invisible unless MathJax renders them. You might want to add more complete/self-contained example.

Comment: I figure out what's wrong with my project. I modified the `src= http://` to `src = https://` in mathjax.html . it works great.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger @Oxinbox  So I wonder why `http://` do not redirected to `https://`  automatically..  now I still have some problems caused by this issue.  **About**  page is not redirected to `https://`  it failed to open.  you can check my [blog](https://changkaizhao.github.io)

Comment: That's expected. GitHub.io redirects from http to https and the MathJax CDN does not, thus the browser blocks the http request to MathJax for security reasons. Always use https if you can.

Comment: I changed the domain to my own, everything solved! Cheer!